# hide the details of d3.chart before choosing something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am having a d3 chart when I load that page the x axis is getting populated with list of dates and y axsis with graph but I don't want to show any details before choosing my dates from date picker and the graph..just I want to display empty canvas..how can i achieve this..
this is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            console.log("obj--", obj)
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];
            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled',
                location: 'fixed'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1')
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }
            });
            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
                $('#listbox').toggle(this.value != "");
            });

            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {

                $('#listbox').empty();

                $('<option>', {
                    text: 'Select your List Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');

                var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                console.log("as".selection);
                $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                    console.log("%o",value)
                    if (value['name'] == selection) {
                        var optionHtml = '';
                        for (var i = 1; i <=20; i++) {

                            var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                            var val = 'val' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);

                            optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '" data-val="'+value[val]+'">' + value[attr] + '</option>';

                        }


                        $("#listbox").css("width", "500px")

                        $("#listbox").css("height", "300px")
                        $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
                        return false;
                    }
                    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                    console.log(selectedOption);

                });

            });
            $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

                console.log("asd", $('#listbox option:selected').attr('data-val'));
                var zxv =  $('#listbox option:selected').attr('data-val')
                $(".bar").attr("y",zxv)
                console.log("test", $(".bar").attr("y",zxv))
                $(".bar").attr("height",'10')


            })
        }
    });
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>D3</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" /> -->

    <style>
        body {
            color: #000;
        }

        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .bar {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .bar:hover {
            fill: brown;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="my_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<div align="center">
    From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" /> To : <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit" />
</div>

<script>
    var jsonURL = 'data.json';

    var myData = [];

    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 80,
        left: 40
    };
    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
    var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', 'o');

    function getDates() {
        return [document.getElementById('field1').value, document.getElementById('field2').value];
    }

    function render(filterByDates) {

        d3.select('svg').remove();

        if (filterByDates) {
            var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
            var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

            myData = myData.filter(function(d) {
                return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;
            });
        }

        xScale.domain(myData.map(function(d) {
            return d.date;
        }));

        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(myData, function(d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

        var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg
                .append('g')
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(hAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                .attr("dy", "-.55em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

        svg
                .append('g')
                .attr("class", "yaxis")
                .call(vAxis)

        svg
                .selectAll(".bar")
                .data(myData)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.date);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.value);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height - yScale(d.value);
                })
                .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 1)

                    tooltip.html(d.value)
                            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                            .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                            .style('opacity', 0)
                    d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                });
    }

    d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {

        myData = data;
        myData.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = new Date(d.date);
            d.name = +d.name;
        });

        render(false);
    });
</script>


<label> List of Tables : </label><br>
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 50px;">
        <select id="dropdown1"></select>
    </div>
    <style>
        #listbox {
            display: none;
        }
        #listbox {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>

    <style>
        rect.bar {
            width: 10px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <div style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: -30px; height: auto;">
        <select id="listbox", multiple></select>
    </div>

</form>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the bars unless you get dates:

```
if (filterByDates) {
    svg
      .selectAll(".bar")
      .data(myData)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      ...
```